# Separate TreeViewItem in few parts xaml wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can separate TreeViewItem in few parts with Grid.Column or anything else to like in the picture: One part to be Label, second part to be Image, third part to be empty place and last part to be CheckBox (for example). 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un81D.jpg)

And my results is too different from this what I need to make, here is the picture with my results.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gRll.png)

And part of my code:

```
<Border Name="SensorsOption" BorderThickness="0 2 2 2" BorderBrush="#dce3e2" Background="#dce3e2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0 2 0 0">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <Border Name="InsideSensorOption" BorderThickness="2 0 2 2" BorderBrush="#dce3e2" Background="#dce3e2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                    <Label Content="Sensors" 
                           Background="#ebf0f0" 
                           Foreground="#1d2326"
                           FontWeight="Bold"
                           FontSize="12"
                           BorderBrush="#dae3e2"
                           BorderThickness="0 0 0 2"
                           Padding="25 6 6 6"/>

                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="21*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="43*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="17*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/good-weather-1/96/weather_icons-64-32.png" Height="24" Width="24" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="T1 S1" />
                        <CheckBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding AirIsChecked}" />

                        <TreeView Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
                            <TreeViewItem>
                                <TreeViewItem.Header>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="68*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="13*" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="19*" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <Label Content="Value" Grid.Column="0" />
                                        <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="http://www.metalsaber.com/images/main_images/rss.gif" Width="30" Height="15" />
                                        <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" IsChecked="{Binding AirValueIsChecked}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </TreeViewItem.Header>
                            </TreeViewItem>
                        </TreeView>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>                
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible by using `Margin` property:

```
<TreeView >
   <TreeViewItem>
      <TreeViewItem.Header>
         <Grid>
             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="68*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="13*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="19*" />
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <Label Content="Value"  Grid.Column="0" />
             <TextBlock Text="Hello" Margin="100,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
             <CheckBox Grid.Column="2" IsChecked="{Binding AirValueIsChecked}" />
          </Grid>
      </TreeViewItem.Header>
   </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

[As MSDN says:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The margin is the space between this element and other elements that
>   will be adjacent when layout creates the user interface (UI). Shared
>   elements might be peer elements (such as other elements in the
>   collection of a common parent control), or might also be this
>   element's parent.

Comment: For me Margin is not solution, because I need when I change the size of window and margin between elements to be changed without I calculate how is be.

Comment: @evelikov92 What happens at the first image if items are not expanded? Images are moved to items or stays at the same position?

Comment: is stayed in the same position.

Comment: @evelikov92 so it means that `Margin` property is used at the first image too. Try to set `Margin="20,0,0,0"`. Maybe narrower width is what you want.